# How do I get my pool heater up and running?

Tags: gas, heater, pool

Anyone know how I can turn on the pool heater? I provided a video of everything here:

https://youtu.be/s8bLVnTt5dk

Model is a Purex triton minimax 400

Note: when I turned the pool heater on in the video at around the last 2 seconds of the video you can hear that whistling that resembles the sound of a hot tea kettle. The smell was gassy and almost like burning. Is this normal for a pool heater? Also any steps I should take too ensure a safe pool warm up if possible?

(Ignore the plastic that lays on top of it I know too take that off when actually attempting)

Thank you for reading and taking the time out too help

Comment: A gassy smell is not normal; it indicates either that the pilot or main burner isn't lighting. I don't know this heater, but either a) the pilot light is not burning and its pilot generator incorrectly reports that it _is_ burning, allowing the pilot gas to just run without ignition; or b) the main gas valve is allowing gas flow without its thermocouple reporting a pilot flame in place. One or both of these conditions is failing.

Comment: thank you for the response. is it possible the gas line is cut which is causing this issue? I was seeing people would turn those 2 black valves before turning on the heater. I left mine off, could that have caused the issue by any chance?

Comment: If a live gas line were cut, you'd smell gas all the time. There could, however, be a cut downstream of the cutoff valve but upstream from the pilot orifice or main burner valve — either would prevent proper lighting of the burner, and would smell of gas. Smell of gas is a _bad sign_ and must be rectified ASAP.

Comment: I see. I read some forums and people said it’s normal too smell gas on the upstart of the pool heater. Did they only mean that for their specific models? Also who would I call out to get looked at this? And is there a way I could check too see if theirs a cut downstream of the cutoff valve?

Comment: I've had gas hot tub heaters (decades) and gas forced-air furnaces (my whole life), and never smelt gas when things were operating correctly. You may decide for yourself whose advice to follow. This is a job for someone versed in gas heating and furnaces, perhaps from a swimming pool maintenance and repair business. Here in California, these folks have contractors' licenses.

Comment: Kind of hard to guess is the igniter firing or is it a standing pilot. Open the cover and find the igniter is it actually lighting but shutting down for a dirty eye or possibly a bad pressure switch, more than a few things to guess at.